# TypeScript not respecting get-only properties?

Tags: typescript, casting, immutability, assignment-operator

Consider following code

```
class A {
    private _f: string;
    get f(): string {
        return this._f;
    }
}
class B {
    f: string;    
    static x(a: A): B {
        // I expect an error in next line because A does not have a setter for 'f'
        return a;
    }
}
let a = new A();
// this line gives error, as expected
a.f = "safe";
let b = B.x(a);
// this will mutate object that I want to be immutable!
b.f = "ouch!";
```

Why does this happen?
(tried with TS 2.4 and 2.3).

Answer (score 1):

After some browsing turned out that it is a [known problem](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347)...